# Getting an image url from sql database using php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to retrieve an image url from a database called flags in the image field to use.

Where am I going wrong with this?

```
<?php
    connect();
    $sql = ("SELECT image FROM members, flags WHERE members.member_id = '$_SESSION[id]' AND flags.id = members.country");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<div id="flag">
<img id="flag" src="$result" width="16px" height="11px"/>
```

Comment: Use a join, escape your query input, don't use whiles when you only expect/use one value of the result set..

Comment: thanks ive updated the code above. is this better? still not working so im going wrong somewhere :/ i've tried echo'ing back $result but just comes back with 'Resource id #7'

Comment: @lennard2011 that's better, but you need to tell mysql what table `image` is coming from: `flags.image`. And you should respond to the answers to the original question, not make them obsolete by updating your question

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `$row` variable from the last mysql_fetch, instead of `$row4` in your new fetch:

```
 while ($row4=mysql_fetch_array($sql3)){
            $sql4 = $row4['image'];   //$row4 here instead of $row
        }
```

And like @halfdan commented, you don't need to use while loops when you're only dealing with one row, and you can replace those two queries with one join query

Answer (score 0):

`$result = mysql_query($sql);` it's only to run the query
you need to add one more statement which fetches the record from talbe, it could be:

1. `$result_set = mysql_fetch_object($result);`
2. `$result_set = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

`if you are using 1 get value by $result_set->image;`

`if you are using 2 get value by $result_set['image'];`